# Mercurial plugin for Eclipse can't find Python--how to fix?

Tags: python, mercurial, eclipse-plugin, osx-lion

I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.1 (Lion). I just downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, and installed the Mercurial plugin. I get the following error message:

> abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in [...assorted Python directories...].

I do have Python 2.6.1 and 3.2.1 installed. I also have a directory `System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`, which is on the list of places it looked for the Mercurial libraries. `hg -y debuginstall` gives me the same message.

What are these libraries named, where is Eclipse likely to have put them when I installed the plugin, and how do I tell Eclipse where they are (or where should I move them to)?

Thanks, Dave

Full error message follows:

> abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in
>   [/usr/platlib/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages /usr/local/bin
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages] (check your install and PYTHONPATH)

Comment: Please post the actual error messages so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody answered me, but I figured out the answer. Maybe it will help someone.

I finally realized that since 'hg -y debuginstall' at the command line was giving me the same error message, it wasn't an Eclipse problem at all (duh). Reinstalling a newer version of Mercurial solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had two installation of mercurial in mac. 
One was installed directly and another using macport.
Removing the direct installation solved the problem.

1. Remove the direct installation using 
   easy_install -m mercurial
2. Update "Mercurial Executable" path to "/opt/local/bin/hg"
   Eclipse->Preference->Team->Mercurial->
3. Restart eclipse